# Error while generating signed build (proguard enable)

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, androidx, kotlin-coroutines

I have added kotlin and kotlin-coroutines in the project recently, that is causing an error while building apk with proguard enable.

This is the error I'm getting.

```
kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$10$1: can't find enclosing method 'java.lang.Object collect$$forInline(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowCollector,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)' in program class kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__BuildersKt$asFlow$$inlined$unsafeFlow$10
```

Proguard file  changes:

```
 -keep class kotlin.** { *; }
    -keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
    -dontwarn kotlin.**
    -dontwarn kotlinx.atomicfu.AtomicBoolean
    -keepclassmembers class **$WhenMappings {
        <fields>;
    }
    -keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
        public <methods>;
    }
    -assumenosideeffects class kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics {
        static void checkParameterIsNotNull(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String);
    }

    -keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory {}
    -keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler {}
    -keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidExceptionPreHandler {}
    -keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory {}

    -keepclassmembernames class kotlinx.** {
        volatile <fields>;
    }
```

In debug mode, it is working fine.

Comment: If that's a warning, you can use `-dontwarn kotlinx.coroutines.**`

Comment: try to add -dontwarn kotlinx.coroutines.flow. in your proguard. check more https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1270

Comment: Yup this worked. I had R8 disabled for checking if default proguard works and those warnings appeared!